# Вывести с ассоциативного массива значение определенного key

Tags: javascript, for

Нужно при нажатии b-1 выполняете функцию f1. Функция должна вывести в out-1 значение сохраненное под ключем two из массива a1. Возвратите это значение.

Есть код:

```js
    let a1 = {
        "one" : 15,
        "two" : 16,
        "five" : 20
        };
```

```html
 <div class="out-1"></div>
 <button class="b-1">b1</button>
```

Большего не смог написать:

```js
let a1 = {
    "one" : 15,
    "two" : 16,
    "five" : 20
    };

    document.querySelector('.b-1').onclick = f1 = ()=>{
        
        for( let i in a1){
            let a = document.querySelector('.out-1').innerHTML = i;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="out-1"></div>
 <button class="b-1">b1</button>
```

Помогите пожалуйста дописать код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вы, кажется, переусложнили.

```js
let a1 = {
    "one" : 15,
    "two" : 16,
    "five" : 20
};

function f1() {
  document.querySelector('.out-1').innerHTML = a1.two;
}

document.querySelector('.b-1').onclick = f1;
```

```html
 <div class="out-1"></div>
 <button class="b-1">b1</button>
```